# Instanciar classe ao iniciar aplicação

Tags: classes, angular, typescript

Gostaria de saber se é possível instanciar uma classe e usar em toda a minha aplicação sem precisar instanciá-la e importá-la. 
Tenho meu app.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnalyticsService } from './@core/utils/analytics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private analytics: AnalyticsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.analytics.trackPageViews();
  }
}
```

Tenho meu app.module:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { LoginComponent } from './pages/autenticacao/login.component';
import { AuthService } from './app.setings';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

E por fim tenho meu AuthService

```
export class AuthService {
    // logica do classe aqui 
}
```

Basicamente queria criar uma instancia de `AuthService` (`new AuthService()`) em app.component ou app.module e por meio disso sempre que eu precisar utilizar a classe AuthService utilize esta que foi criada ao iniciar minha aplicação, sem eu precisar importa-la e criar uma nova instancia dela.

Código esta assim:

```
    import { API_CONFIG, AuthService } from '../../../app.setings';

@Injectable()
export class CidadeService {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

    // criei uma nova intancia de AuthService
  }

}
```

Quero poder importa-la em app.module ou app.component e sempre que precisar simplesmente chamo e a utilizo

```
@Injectable()
export class CidadeService {

    metodo() {
        AuthService.outroMetodo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Na verdade você não está criando uma nova instância, o Angular mantém a mesma instância em memória e sempre te entrega essa mesma instância quando você chama pelo construtor do component.

Comment: Eu consegui o resultado esperado meio que por uma gambiara, veja se existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso. Retirei o `export` da classe e no fim do arquivo coloquei `const _AuthService = new AuthService();
export const authService = _AuthService;`